# QML: Text Rendering Problems

Tags: opengl, qml, qt5.2

Using `Text { ... }` in QML produces strange problems for me. In most of the laptops it works fine, but in some there are a lot of characters missing. For example if the text is `"Abcdefgh"` it might show up as `"Ab e g "`. I don't know what the problem is. If I change the `renderType` property of `Text {}` to `Text.NativeRendering` however then the problem disappears but in a few places the some characters become unreadable/skewed. Is there an issue with QML text rendering or something to do with OpenGL drivers, video cards etc ?

Also in systems where this problem occurs there is a random crash during application start up. Could be due to a different issue but just wanted to write down here in case somebody knows there is a relationship between the crashes and the rendering problem.

What could be the Problem and what's the solution ?

{Qt/QML 5.2.0, MinGW 4.8, Win 7}

Comment: Same here. If I use ANGLE, instead of missing letters there are filled rectangles for each letter. Switching renderType does not help. Qt 5.3.1, Win7. This only happens on one machine, which is quite low on RAM.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: Setting renderType to Text.NativeRendering actually _does_ fix the problem. Text is not prettily anti-aliased anymore, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QML text rendering issue with custom OpenGL item active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826182/qml-text-rendering-issue-with-custom-opengl-item-active)

Comment: We still see this issue with Qt5.15.2 using eglfs_kms as rendering backend on i.MX8MM SoC with Mesa 20.0.2 and etnaviv GPU driver (Linux 5.10).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying 5.3 and seeing if the problems still occur. I remember lots of font rendering issues being fixed there.